# ¿Como sumar arrays de tuplas en Python?

Tags: python

Quiero sumar dos arrays , `follow_dismiss` y `display` que tienen solo un valor :

```
follow_dismiss
[(408L,), (14L,), (59L,), (6L,), (32L,), (62L,), (59L,), (120L,), (53L,), (150L,), (3L,), (1L,), (60L,), (1L,), (126L,), (41L,), (239L,), (163L,), (11L,), (42L,), (1L,), (2L,), (5L,), (1L,), (2L,), (4L,)]
display
[(382L,), (6L,), (295L,), (1L,), (8L,), (33L,), (30L,), (24L,), (5L,), (233L,), (1L,), (65L,), (21L,), (20L,), (86L,), (171L,), (2L,), (29L,), (2L,), (3L,), (1L,)]
```

Vienen de SQL consultas, por ejemplo :

```
cur.execute("""-- nombre de fois ou l'on propose une pub a l'utilisateur par utilisateur
SELECT COUNT (swipe.state) FROM swipe
  WHERE swipe.state= 1 OR swipe.state = 4 or swipe.state=7
    GROUP BY swipe.subscriber_id
      ORDER BY swipe.subscriber_id;""")
    display = cur.fetchall()
```

Para obtener :

```
[790, 20, 9, ...]
```

Otro ejemplo :

```
[(1,2), (3, 4)] + [(2, 3), (1, 3)] = [(3,5), (4, 7)]
```

No funciona ni eso :

```
SUM_follow_dismiss_display_i = [x + y for x, y in zip(follow_dismiss, display)]
```

Porque da :

```
[(408L, 381L), (14L, 6L), (59L, 294L), (6L, 1L), (32L, 8L), (62L, 33L), (59L, 30L), (120L, 24L), (53L, 5L), (150L, 233L), (3L, 1L), (1L, 65L), (60L, 21L), (1L, 20L), (126L, 86L), (41L, 171L), (239L, 2L), (163L, 29L), (11L, 2L), (42L, 3L), (1L, 1L)]
```

Ni eso :

```
SUM_follow_dismiss_display_i = map(add,follow_dismiss,display)
```

Que da :

```
SUM_follow_dismiss_display_i = map(add,follow_dismiss,display)
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "NoneType") to tuple
```

Lo hizo porque quiero dividir cada casilla con su equivalente del otro array en un último array, matriz de resultados. Sin emargo map(truediv, arry1, arry2) no funciona porque me dice que  :

```
print follow_dismiss
print SUM_follow_dismiss_display_i
m_i = map(truediv, SUM_follow_dismiss, SUM_follow_dismiss_display_i)

[(408L,), (14L,), (59L,), (6L,), (32L,), (62L,), (59L,), (120L,), (53L,), (150L,), (3L,), (1L,), (60L,), (1L,), (126L,), (41L,), (239L,), (163L,), (11L,), (42L,), (1L,), (2L,), (5L,), (1L,), (2L,), (4L,)]
[(408L, 381L), (14L, 6L), (59L, 294L), (6L, 1L), (32L, 8L), (62L, 33L), (59L, 30L), (120L, 24L), (53L, 5L), (150L, 233L), (3L, 1L), (1L, 65L), (60L, 21L), (1L, 20L), (126L, 86L), (41L, 171L), (239L, 2L), (163L, 29L), (11L, 2L), (42L, 3L), (1L, 1L)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./testPostreSQLPython.py", line 72, in <module>
    m_i = map(truediv, SUM_follow_dismiss, SUM_follow_dismiss_display_i)
TypeError: argument 2 to map() must support iteration
```

Comment: Marine ¿como quieres sumar las tuplas exactamente?, ¿tienes más de un valor o solo uno por tupla? Por ejemplo, ¿que deberia dar `[(1,2), (3, 4)] + [(2,  3), (1, 3)]`? Intenta colocar un ejemplo con dos arrays pequeños y la salida que esperas obtener en cada paso. Por otro lado, ¿son listas o arrays de NumPy? Saludos.

Comment: He creado una respuesta para hacer lo que creo que deseas tanto con NumPy o `zip` de la biblioteca estándar. Si ese array solo te sirve para dividir `follow_dismiss` entre el se podría hacer todo en un solo paso para evitar variables intermedias. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si puedes usar NumPy dado que tu estructura es basicamente una matriz, simplemente concatena:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([(408,), (14,), (59,), (6,)])
b = np.array([(382,), (6,), (295,), (1,)])

c = a + b
```

La salida es:

> ```
> array([[790],
>        [ 20],
>        [354],
>        [  7]])
> ```

Otra opción sin usar Numpy podria ser `zip` o `itertools.izip` en Python 2:

- Python 2.x:

  ```
  from itertools import izip

  a = [(408,), (14,), (59,), (6,)]
  b = [(382,), (6,), (295,), (1,)]
  c = [[c+d for c, d in izip(row1, row2)] for row1, row2 in izip(a, b)]
  ```
- Python 3.x:

  ```
  a = [(408,), (14,), (59,), (6,)]
  b = [(382,), (6,), (295,), (1,)]
  c = [[c+d for c, d in zip(row1, row2)] for row1, row2 in zip(a, b)]
  ```

En Python 2 es valido también usar `zip`, la diferencia es que `zip` en Python 2 retorna una lista y no un iterador como hace en Python 3. De todas forma el uso de NumPy es la mejor opción tanto en eficiencia como en simplicidad.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias ! ¿Y sabes [como hacerlo respecto a un index](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/72035/como-sumar-arrays-de-tuplas-en-python-en-respecto-a-index) ? Es por decir `[(23L,1),(12L,3),(10L,5)]` con `[(23L,1),(8L,3),(10L,10)]` daría : `[(46L,1),(16L,3),(10L,5),(10L,10)]` ¿o una cosa mas simple ?

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo dos array de valores, puedes ayudarte de la función `zip`:

```
uno= [1,2,3,4,5]
dos = [6,7,8,9,10]

[x + y for x, y in zip(uno, dos )]
```

***Resultado:***

> ```
> [7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
> ```