# ¿Como sumar arrays de tuplas en Python en respecto a index?

Tags: python

Quiero sumar dos arrays , `follow_dismiss` y `display`de tamaño differente que vienene de consultas SQL que tienen un valor y un index sobre los index que vienene de una consulta sql :

```
cur.execute("""-- nombre de fois ou l'utilisateur fait ce qu'on attend de lui par utilisateur
SELECT COUNT (swipe.state),swipe.subscriber_id FROM swipe
  WHERE swipe.state= 2 OR swipe.state = 3 or swipe.state=5
  OR swipe.state =6 or swipe.state=8 or swipe.state=9
    GROUP BY swipe.subscriber_id
      ORDER BY swipe.subscriber_id;""")
follow_dismiss = cur.fetchall()
print "follow_dismiss"
```

y

```
    cur.execute("""-- nombre de fois ou l'on propose une pub a l'utilisateur par utilisateur
SELECT COUNT (swipe.state),swipe.subscriber_id FROM swipe
  WHERE swipe.state= 1 OR swipe.state = 4 or swipe.state=7
    GROUP BY swipe.subscriber_id
      ORDER BY swipe.subscriber_id;""")
```

dan :

```
follow_dismiss
[(409L, 13), (14L, 54), (59L, 68), (6L, 150), (32L, 152), (62L, 156), (59L, 158), (120L, 160), (53L, 161), (150L, 162), (3L, 169), (1L, 171), (60L, 172), (1L, 177), (126L, 179), (41L, 185), (239L, 189), (163L, 190), (11L, 216), (42L, 223), (1L, 272), (2L, 286), (5L, 289), (1L, 292), (2L, 294), (4L, 296)]
display
[(384L, 13), (6L, 54), (300L, 68), (1L, 150), (8L, 152), (33L, 156), (30L, 158), (24L, 160), (5L, 161), (233L, 162), (1L, 171), (65L, 172), (21L, 179), (20L, 185), (86L, 189), (171L, 190), (2L, 216), (29L, 223), (2L, 276), (3L, 286), (1L, 296)]
```

Quiero obtener :

[(793,13), (20,54),...]

A qui esta lo que he intentado :

```
follow_dismiss=[(409L, 13), (14L, 54), (59L, 68), (6L, 150), (32L, 152), (62L, 156), (59L, 158), (120L, 160), (53L, 161), (150L, 162), (3L, 169), (1L, 171), (60L, 172), (1L, 177), (126L, 179), (41L, 185), (239L, 189), (163L, 190), (11L, 216), (42L, 223), (1L, 272), (2L, 286), (5L, 289), (1L, 292), (2L, 294), (4L, 296)]
display=[(384L, 13), (6L, 54), (300L, 68), (1L, 150), (8L, 152), (33L, 156), (30L, 158), (24L, 160), (5L, 161), (233L, 162), (1L, 171), (65L, 172), (21L, 179), (20L, 185), (86L, 189), (171L, 190), (2L, 216), (29L, 223), (2L, 276), (3L, 286), (1L, 296)]

def column_sums(a, b):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len(b)):  
        if a[i][2]=b[j][2]
            result[i][1] =a[i][1]+b[j][1] 
        else if a[i][2]<b[j][2]
            result[i][1]=a[i][1]
            result[i][2]= a[j][2]
            j = j-1 # para quedar
        else if a[i][2]>b[j][2]
            result[i][1]= b[j][1]
            result[i][2]= b[j][2]
            i = i-1 # para quedar

a = colums_sums(follow_dismiss,display)
print a
```

Pero me dice :

```
./testPython.py: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./testPython.py: line 1: `follow_dismiss=[(409L, 13), (14L, 54), (59L, 68), (6L, 150), (32L, 152), (62L, 156), (59L, 158), (120L, 160), (53L, 161), (150L, 162), (3L, 169), (1L, 171), (60L, 172), (1L, 177), (126L, 179), (41L, 185), (239L, 189), (163L, 190), (11L, 216), (42L, 223), (1L, 272), (2L, 286), (5L, 289), (1L, 292), (2L, 294), (4L, 296)]'
```

**Actualizacion 23/05/2017**

Hizo con la ayuda de la respuesta de FJSevilla :

```
    cur.execute("""-- nombre de fois ou l'utilisateur fait ce qu'on attend de lui par utilisateur
    SELECT COUNT (swipe.state),swipe.subscriber_id FROM swipe
      WHERE swipe.state= 2 OR swipe.state = 3 or swipe.state=5
      OR swipe.state =6 or swipe.state=8 or swipe.state=9
        GROUP BY swipe.subscriber_id
          ORDER BY swipe.subscriber_id;""")
    follow_dismiss_sql = cur.fetchall()

    cur.execute("""-- nombre de fois ou l'on propose une pub a l'utilisateur par utilisateur
SELECT COUNT (swipe.state),swipe.subscriber_id FROM swipe
  WHERE swipe.state= 1 OR swipe.state = 4 or swipe.state=7
    GROUP BY swipe.subscriber_id
      ORDER BY swipe.subscriber_id;""")
    display_sql = cur.fetchall()
    follow_dismiss = np.array(follow_dismiss_sql)
    display = np.array(display_sql)

    print follow_dismiss_sql
    print display_sql

    df = pd.DataFrame(follow_dismiss+display,  columns = ('counts',  'id') )
    suma = df.groupby("id").sum()
    out = pd.np.column_stack((suma.counts.values, suma.index.values))
    print(out)


df = pd.DataFrame(follow_dismiss+display,  columns = ('counts',  'id') )
suma = df.groupby("id").sum()
out = pd.np.column_stack((suma.counts.values, suma.index.values))
print(out)
```

Pero me dice que :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(follow_dismiss+display,  columns = ('counts',  'id') )
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (26,2) (21,2)
```

Pero funciona cuando hizo la respuesta de FJSevilla ...

Comment: el array se define como a=[] y si es un array de arrays es a=[[,],[,]].. no son parentesis, son llaves lo que necesitas en cada item...

Comment: @gbianchi esto viene de consultas SQL, como puede utilisarle para tratarle con Python ?

Comment: haciendo un replace? no se como te viene asi desde un sql...

Comment: @gbianchi con `np.array(sql_query)`. Le  mostraré en la actualización  ;) Pero ya no se como hacer la suma sobre los index.

Comment: Si las consulta se hace sobre la misma tabla al mismo tiempo podrias obtener las sumas simplemente agrupando las dos consultas en una. Independientemente a esto, ¿Puedes usar [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)? Manejar datos y agrupar como lo que tu quieres aquí es realmente simple usandolo.

Comment: @Marine1 Bash no entiende python, para ejecutar código Python necesitas un intérprete de Python. El intérprete de Python dice que el sangrado de tu código es incorrecto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando Pandas con [`DataFrame.gropby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) el agrupamiento es muy simple:

```
import pandas as pd

follow_dismiss= [(409, 13), (14, 54), (59, 68), (6, 150), (32, 152), (62, 156), (59, 158), (120, 160), (53, 161), (150, 162), (3, 169), (1, 171), (60, 172), (1, 177), (126, 179), (41, 185), (239, 189), (163, 190), (11, 216), (42, 223), (1, 272), (2, 286), (5, 289), (1, 292), (2, 294), (4, 296)]
display= [(384, 13), (6, 54), (300, 68), (1, 150), (8, 152), (33, 156), (30, 158), (24, 160), (5, 161), (233, 162), (1, 171), (65, 172), (21, 179), (20, 185), (86, 189), (171, 190), (2, 216), (29, 223), (2, 276), (3, 286), (1, 296)]

#Creamos un dataframe con las dos columnas
df = pd.DataFrame(follow_dismiss+display,  columns = ('counts',  'id') )
#Agrupamos por id sumando el resto de columnas
suma = df.groupby("id").sum()

#Podemos seguir trabajando sobre el DataFrame pero si queremos la salida como array NumPy basta con:
out = pd.np.column_stack((suma.counts.values, suma.index.values))
print(out)
```

**Edición:**

Si los datos de entrada son arrays de NumPy no podemos hacer `follow_dismiss + display` porque esto lo que hace es intentar sumar elemento por elemento ambos arrays, no concatenarlos. Para ello usamos `numpy.concatenate()`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

follow_dismiss= np.array([(409, 13), (14, 54), (59, 68), (6, 150), (32, 152), (62, 156), (59, 158), (120, 160), (53, 161), (150, 162), (3, 169), (1, 171), (60, 172), (1, 177), (126, 179), (41, 185), (239, 189), (163, 190), (11, 216), (42, 223), (1, 272), (2, 286), (5, 289), (1, 292), (2, 294), (4, 296)])
display= np.array([(384, 13), (6, 54), (300, 68), (1, 150), (8, 152), (33, 156), (30, 158), (24, 160), (5, 161), (233, 162), (1, 171), (65, 172), (21, 179), (20, 185), (86, 189), (171, 190), (2, 216), (29, 223), (2, 276), (3, 286), (1, 296)])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate((follow_dismiss, display),axis=0),  columns = ('counts',  'id') )
suma = df.groupby("id").sum()

out = pd.np.column_stack((suma.counts.values, suma.index.values))
print(out)
```

**Salida:**

> ```
> array([[793,  13],
>        [ 20,  54],
>        [359,  68],
>        [  7, 150],
>        [ 40, 152],
>        [ 95, 156],
>        [ 89, 158],
>        [144, 160],
>        [ 58, 161],
>        [383, 162],
>        [  3, 169],
>        [  2, 171],
>        [125, 172],
>        [  1, 177],
>        [147, 179],
>        [ 61, 185],
>        [325, 189],
>        [334, 190],
>        [ 13, 216],
>        [ 71, 223],
>        [  1, 272],
>        [  2, 276],
>        [  5, 286],
>        [  5, 289],
>        [  1, 292],
>        [  2, 294],
>        [  5, 296]], dtype=int64)
> ```

Comment: hmmm... su coda funciona bien pero cuando traigolo en lo mio me dice : `df = pd.DataFrame(follow_dismiss+display,  columns = ('counts',  'id') )
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (26,2) (21,2)`

Comment: @Marine1 eso ocurre si tus datos de entrada (los arrays) son arrays de Numpy por ejemplo. Con `follow_dismiss+display` lo que se intenta es unir ambos arrays en uno, esto debes adaptarlo según el tipo de dato tus arrays, si no lo conoces haz `type(follow_dismiss)` a ver que optienes. He editado la pregunta añadiendo otro ejemplo debajo del que había usando listas, mira a ver si te funciona así, si no averigua el tipo de datos que son los arrays o pasalos a un arrray de Numpy usando `follow_dismiss = numpy.array(follow_dismiss) `y `display  = numpy.array(display)`. Saludos.